# how to replace numpy 1.24.2 with 1.23.5 correctly

Tags: numpy, pip, package

Can you please tell me how can I install the older version of `numpy 1.23.5` on Ubunutu `20.04`, because I'm getting this error:

```
$ pip3 install numpy==1.23.5
Collecting numpy==1.23.5
  Using cached numpy-1.23.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.1 MB)
ERROR: tensorflow 2.12.0 has requirement protobuf!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.20.3, but you'll have protobuf 3.6.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorboard 2.12.0 has requirement protobuf>=3.19.6, but you'll have protobuf 3.6.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: pandas 1.5.3 has requirement python-dateutil>=2.8.1, but you'll have python-dateutil 2.7.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: pandas 1.5.3 has requirement pytz>=2020.1, but you'll have pytz 2019.3 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.24.2
```

And whenever I try to uninstall the older version I get:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall numpy
Found existing installation: numpy 1.17.4
Not uninstalling numpy at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'numpy'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem as follows:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy*

pip3 install numpy==1.23.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have some conflicts in packages.
I would just start with creating a fresh env to do that.
If you want to use the current env, you should uninstall all conflicted packages (i.e `pandas, tensorflow, tensorboard, numpy`), than just install the wanted numpy version